# Haciendo Merge en Maquina virtual

Tags: servidor

tengo un problema con mi maquina virtual de Hyper-V, mi servidor hizo los respaldos en cada maquina virtual, a lo que yo quiero juntar todos los respaldos en uno solo, así es que estoy haciendo merge por cada checkpoint, pero el último que hice se está tardando mucho no se si eso sea normal o si le doy cancelar, puede funcionar normalmente?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hmmm, y dónde está el error del código? De hecho, dónde está el código?? Esta comunidad es para problemas de programación, te recomiendo que visites una comunidad específica para sysadmin o algo por el estilo, seguramente tendrán más idea y te podrán ayudar mejor

Comment: Ah ok, no sabía que solo era para códigos esta página. Gracias